# Will the VS 2010 SP1 be available through windows update

Tags: visual-studio-2010

or should I download and install it manually?

Yes, I know I can already download it, but I'd prefer to do that through WU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio updates (including SP releases and other QFEs) rarely end up on Windows Update.  Just about the only time you'll see them end up there is for a security patch to the framework (extremely rare for Visual Studio itself).

Comment: But I get a lot of MS Office updates.

Comment: The Visual Studio group at Microsoft has not opted to participate as frequently in the WU system; most QFEs are released for specific customer segments, and those customers will usually be able to find the update easily enough.  Also, many of the updates for Office are for lower-risk security issues, which certainly meets the bar for a WU release.

Answer (score 1):

Not positive but it looks like the kind of update that may not even appear in the optional list. Almost definitely not the required windows update list. I say manually install it.

Comment: There are a lot of updates for MS Office. It is not a part of windows though